# How to create custom 3D "areas" at runtime

Tags: unity

I've been puzzled for a few days trying to solve this problem, so far with no results.

On a map, currently a Terrain, I'd need to have some "areas" which can be controlled by a specific players. **The shape of those areas can arbitrarily change during the course of the game**, such as you add a  marker in any point, and the area evolves (like a spline, say) to pass through that point too.

The problem isn't drawing the boundary itself, of course, but having the GameObjects detecting the area they are in.

Currently I have absolutely zero idea on how to make this **exactly**.

---

*I've thought about a nice approximation, which is splitting the terrain in fixed chunks, and having the player control them "chunk by chunk": every chunk can have its own collider, and that should be easy if not trivial. So the question is how to do it "properly", since I already have this workaround.*

Comment: I would create a polygon from the points, do a is-point-in-polygon check. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Felsir you mean, without using Unity components and functions like `Collider`s, instead having a custom-made function to do the check? That's brilliant and obvious, silly me! Could you post it as an answer, if that's really what you meant?

Comment: That is exactly what I meant :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using an hybrid approach, inspired by:

- my original workaround
- @`Felsir`'s post
- @`dnkdrone.vs.drones`'s post

## Solution

I have **Chunks**, which may have an owner or be **contested**.

- *Inside* a contested Chunk, different players have their areas of influence.
- Instead of using a definite polygon/line border, inside the Chunk itself every player may place **Flag**s.
- The Chunk itself is dividend into equally distanced **ChunkPoint**s.
- A ChunkPoint's owner is the nearest Flag's owner.
- Chunk's % ownership is how many ChunkPoints you own.

[image: first screenshot]
[image: screenshot with sub-areas]

## Sources

Using a **polygon** approach turned out to be too complex because I had to detect the order of the points, and they could with time take very complex shapes, which wasn't obvious how to handle.

I considered using **voronoi**'s before realising that a ChunkPoint map was much easier and equally good for what I needed to do (but *trying* to use them was the source of inspiration that got me there).

In the **original workaround** idea, Chunks weren't "contested", they were just fully-owned by a single player, and that's why I didn't like them.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest this approach.

Use [voronoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) 2d subdivision for your space (in the example the central points distr is (pseudo)random, but you can insert your logic)

[image]

Then asociate a value to each point that results (in the example image) in different color for each cell

[image]

You can play with the number of point and/or distribution to get more defined shapes. For the voronoi diagram property, when you click on the map , the origin point nearest to your click position identifies the voronoi cell you are in.

Comment: But isn't this basically equivalent to my workaround "divide it into chunks"?

Comment: you overcome Unity colliders

Answer (score 4):

Create a polygon from the points, do a "is-point-in-polygon" check. So whenever the players add a point that would expand the "area" regenerate the polygon. On the update do a simple position check against that polygon to determine if an object or player is inside the area or not.