# Creating three-dimensional biomes

Tags: c#

I have an idea for a space-based game where there are different sectors of control. These would be set up in a manner similar to terrain biomes, where there will be clusters with limited space between them where there are 'mixed' biomes or even no biomes whatsoever, indicating no 'side' has control over that region.

There are a plethora of articles on the web these days about how to create two dimensional biome maps, but I have seen none about making three-dimensional maps. Has anyone done any coding like this before? My Google-fu is strong but I haven't found any significant pages on it.

I will continue to work on it solo, but as a beginning, solo programmer I expect I will be quite slow on it. I was just wondering if anyone had done this already.

Comment: Looking at answers, you should probably give us a better description of how should they look like, what rules apply, convex/non-convex, polygon/curve borders etc.? Image always helps.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [Voronoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) subdivision.
I gave similar answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104498/how-to-create-custom-3d-areas-at-runtime/104500#104500) for a map (2d) biomes. You may generalize it in 3d.

[image]

Then asociate a value to each point that results (in the example image) in different color for each cell

[image]