# Procedural Islands Voronoi Pattern

Tags: unity, c#, procedural-generation, procedural

I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible, as I've found out the last few days this is a very difficult topic. I'd like to generate multiple flat islands, formed by a voronoi diagram. I've followed a long and (for me) difficult tutorial of building a procedural hexagonal grid just to find out it looks to artificial.

I'd like to create a plane with faces divided in a voronoi diagram, and extrude multiple groups upwards to create islands. With that I'd like to achieve something similar as this: http://applemagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/image2.jpg

Please help to get me started in the right direction, since my approach might be wrong in itself.

**EDIT:**

I've found this: https://github.com/jceipek/Unity-delaunay. Which draws lines in a voronoi diagram. Now I'm guessing the next step is to convert this to a mesh. Then I'd have to highlight random faces to be extruded to create the islands. Maybe this could be done with perlin noise, which I've just learned about. Extruding might not be the best way. Maybe deleting the faces that won't be land, and creating fall of edges (Like Wardy said).  I'm doing my best to figure this out on my own, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on procedural generation: http://www.jgallant.com/procedurally-generating-wrapping-world-maps-in-unity-csharp-part-1/

Comment: shouldn't be too bad to do ... Init a base array the size of your map / a chunk then in to it load values using x,y voronoi that will give you an array of voronoi values, from that take all that are above a certain threshold and plot those points on a plane (x,z with all the same y's) That should give the tops of the islands, then you just need to add your fall off edges, which you can probably generate by taking adjacent points and 2 other points with very low y values and generating a quad then add details.

Comment: Thanks Wardy for your input, but I've read your comment a few times but don't fully understand what you're saying. I'd like to explain what parts I don't understand, but I can't even do that. Maybe you can help me at my pace, from the point I am at now. I've found this: https://github.com/jceipek/Unity-delaunay . Which draws a random voronoi diagram in lines. Can you help me convert that to a mesh? Everything is there, but it's lines instead of a mesh.. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Generate a "map" as described in the link william provided, where the result in green that's the top of an island, blue is the space around the island. The problem here is that your question is really too big in scope to be able to answer, maybe if you got half way through doing this and had trouble with a particular function you could give us your function and ask about that, procedural generation is not just something we "pick up" it often takes a long time to get right

Comment: I've answered similar questions here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104498/how-to-create-custom-3d-areas-at-runtime/104500#104500 and here : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103411/topdown-island-generation/103490#103490 let me know.

Comment: Good explanation and breakdown and working code here - https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/02/24/to-voronoi-and-beyond/